# Spring Boot not able to update sharded collection on azure cosmos db(MongoDb)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, sharding

I have a collection "documentDev" present in the database with sharding key as 'dNumber' 
Sample Document :

```
{
"_id" : "12831221wadaee23",
"dNumber" : "115",
"processed": false
}
```

If I try to update this document through any query tool using a command like -

```
db.documentDev.update({
  "_id" : ObjectId("12831221wadaee23"),
  "dNumber":"115"
},{
    $set:{"processed": true}}, 
{ multi: false, upsert: false}
)}`
```

It updates the document properly. 
But if I do use spring boot's mongorepository command like
    DocumentRepo.save(Object) 
it throws an exception

> - Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 61: 'query in command must target a single shard key' on server by3prdddc01-docdb-3.documents.azure.com:10255. The full response is { "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 61, "errmsg" : "query in command must target a single shard key", "$err" : "query in command must target a single shard key" }

This is my DocumentObject:

```
@Document(collection = "documentDev")
public class DocumentDev
{
@Id
private String id;
private String dNumber;
private String fileName;
private boolean processed;
}
```

This is my Repository Class -

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentRepo extends MongoRepository<DocumentDev, 
String> { }
```

and value i am trying to update

> - Value : doc : 
>     {
>     "_id" : "12831221wadaee23",
>     "dNumber" : "115",
>     "processed": true
>     }

the function I am trying to execute :

```
@Autowired
DocumentRepo docRepo;

docRepo.save(doc); // Fails to execute
```

Note: I have sharding enabled on dNumber field. And I am successfully able to update using Native queries on NoSQL Tool.
I was also able to execute the Repository save operation on Non sharded collection.

Update: I am able to update the document by creating native query using MongoTemplate - My Query looks like this -

```
public DocumentDev updateProcessedFlag(DocumentDev request) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(request.getId()));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("dNumber").is(request.getDNumber()));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("processed", request.isProcessed());
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, request.getClass());
    return request;
}
```

But this is not a generic solution as any other field might have update and my document may have other fields as well.

Comment: did you find a better solution ? I'm having the same issue but with the C# driver.

Comment: Not yet.Still using the workaround only

Comment: There's a specific attribute in spring-data-mongodb:3.x that addresses this now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538573/specifing-a-sharded-collection-with-spring-data-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, solved with following hack:

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveMongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate(ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory,
            MongoConverter converter, MyService service) {
        return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory, converter) {
            @Override
            protected Mono<UpdateResult> doUpdate(String collectionName, Query query, UpdateDefinition update,
                    Class<?> entityClass, boolean upsert, boolean multi) {
                query.addCriteria(new Criteria("shardKey").is(service.getShardKey()));
                return super.doUpdate(collectionName, query, update, entityClass, upsert, multi);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Would be nice to have an annotation @ShardKey to mark document field as shard and have it added to query automatically.

Answer (score 0):

i am hacking this by create a custom repository:

```
public interface CosmosCustomRepository<T> {
    void customSave(T entity);
    void customSave(T entity, String collectionName);
}
```

the implement for this repository:

```
public class CosmosCustomRepositoryImpl<T> implements CosmosCustomRepository<T> {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void customSave(T entity) {
        mongoTemplate.upsert(createQuery(entity), createUpdate(entity), entity.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public void customSave(T entity, String collectionName) {
        mongoTemplate.upsert(createQuery(entity), createUpdate(entity), collectionName);
    }

    private Update createUpdate(T entity) {
        Update update = new Update();
        for (Field field : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.get(entity) != null) {
                    update.set(field.getName(), field.get(entity));
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return update;
    }

    private Query createQuery(T entity) {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        for (Field field : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.get(entity) != null) {
                    if (field.getName().equals("id")) {
                        return new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(field.get(entity)));
                    }
                    criteria.and(field.getName()).is(field.get(entity));
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new Query(criteria);
    }
}
```

your `DocumentRepo` will extends this new custom repository.

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentRepo extends MongoRepository<DocumentDev, String>, CosmosCustomRepository<DocumentDev> { }
```

To save new document, just use new customSave

```
@Autowired
DocumentRepo docRepo;

docRepo.customSave(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the custom repository approach, I got an error because spring is expecting a Cosmos entity to be available in the custom implementation {EntityName}CustomRepositoryImpl, so I renamed the implementation. I also added code for:

- The case when entity has inherited fields
- Shard key is not always the Id, we should add it along with the id: { "shardkeyName": "shardValue" }
- Adding generated ObjectId to the entity for new documents

  ```
   public class DocumentRepositoryImpl<T> implements CosmosRepositoryCustom<T> {

      @Autowired
      protected MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

      @Override
      public T customSave(T entity) {
          WriteResult writeResult = mongoTemplate.upsert(createQuery(entity), createUpdate(entity), entity.getClass());
          setIdForEntity(entity,writeResult);
          return entity;
      }

      @Override
      public T customSave(T entity, String collectionName) {
          WriteResult writeResult = mongoTemplate.upsert(createQuery(entity), createUpdate(entity), collectionName);
          setIdForEntity(entity,writeResult);
          return entity;
      }

      @Override
      public void customSave(List<T> entities) {
          if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(entities)){
              entities.forEach(entity -> customSave(entity));
          }
      }

      public <T> Update createUpdate(T entity){
          Update update = new Update();
          for (Field field : getAllFields(entity)) {
              try {
                  field.setAccessible(true);
                  if (field.get(entity) != null) {
                      update.set(field.getName(), field.get(entity));
                  }
              } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                  LOGGER.error("Error creating update for entity",e);
              }
          }
          return update;
      }

      public <T> Query createQuery(T entity) {
          Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
          for (Field field : getAllFields(entity)) {
              try {
                  field.setAccessible(true);
                  if (field.get(entity) != null) {
                      if (field.getName().equals("id")) {
                          Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(field.get(entity)));
                          query.addCriteria(new Criteria(SHARD_KEY_NAME).is(SHARD_KEY_VALUE));
                          return query;
                      }
                      criteria.and(field.getName()).is(field.get(entity));
                  }
              } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                  LOGGER.error("Error creating query for entity",e);
              }
          }
          return new Query(criteria);
      }

      private <T> List<Field> getAllFields(T entity) {
          List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
          fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));
          Class<?> c = entity.getClass().getSuperclass();
          if(!c.equals(Object.class)){
              fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(c.getDeclaredFields()));
          }
          return fields;
      }

      public <T> void setIdForEntity(T entity,WriteResult writeResult){
          if(null != writeResult && null != writeResult.getUpsertedId()){
              Object upsertId = writeResult.getUpsertedId();
              entity.setId(upsertId.toString());
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I am using spring-boot-starter-mongodb:1.5.1 with spring-data-mongodb:1.9.11

Answer (score 0):

A more recent and simple approach I've figured out recently is to use the `@Sharded({shardKey1, shardKey2, ...})` spring annotation like so:

```
@Document(collection = "documentDev")
@Sharded(shardKey = {"dNumber"})
public class DocumentDev {
  @Id private String id;
  private String dNumber;
  private String fileName;
  private boolean processed;
}
```

This is going to be picked up by `MongoRepository` automatically.
And here is the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#sharding

Enjoy coding!